# Joists not resting on middle wall sill plate, created unlevel floor above

Tags: basement, joists, sill

[image]

You can't really see that well from picture, I may take some new ones to show the issue more clearly.  This is a middle wall in my basement, the joists go from a wall passing over this one, to the perimeter wall of the foundation. The problem is that a couple of the joists don't touch the middle wall's sill plate at all, and have nearly an inch gap. I wouldn't care so much, but this has resulted in the floor above being unlevel. I have a block foundation, and that sill plate doesn't even seem attached to anything.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How old is the construction?

Comment: The house was built in 1921, but the crawlspace I took the img from is a new extension created sometime in the late 70's I think.  This middle wall was part of the original structure, i think it might have been the original perimeter wall.